# QT Callback with result after download is completed

Tags: qt, qt5, qtnetwork

I have a QT application where several different subcomponents need to fetch data from the internet. I want to have one `Network` class that will do all the network interaction and then notify the caller in some way. I couldn't figure out how to do this with slots, so I coded a callback solution:

```
void  Network::downloadFile(QString& urlstr, const std::function<void (QString, QByteArray, QNetworkReply::NetworkError)>& callback) {
    auto processDownload = [&]() {
        QNetworkReply * reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply *>(sender());
        QByteArray result;
        QString filename = reply->url().fileName();
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) { // Success
            result = reply->readAll();
         }
        callback(filename, result, reply->error());
        reply->deleteLater();
    };

    QNetworkReply *reply = nam_->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(urlstr)));
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, this, &Network::downloadProgress);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, processDownload);
}
```

However I get a segfault as soon as `callback` is called. I tried several different ways to define the callback, and even having it empty, it still crashes (segfault mostly, sometimes bad function call). It is defined as:

`std::function<void(QJsonObject, QNetworkReply::NetworkError)> f = std::bind(&MainWindow::onResult, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3);`

I resorted to doing something like `static_cast<parent_class*>(this->parent())->onResult(..)` but this is not really good decoupling. How can I do this in a way that I can pass (or signal to) any generic std::function?

EDIT: Downloadfile is usually called like this:

```
void MainWindow::DoNetworkRQ(QString url) {
    std::function<void(QJsonObject, QNetworkReply::NetworkError)> f = std::bind(&MainWindow::onResult, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3);
    network_.downloadFile(url, f);
}
```

Which results in a segfault. How do I do this in a QT way?

Comment: C++ basics - your `callback` variable goes out of scope. Copy it instead passing just a reference to the lambda.

Comment: I want to access the object instance, so I can't copy it, right? What would be a correct "QT" way to do this? @chehrlic

Comment: Can you show how you're calling `downloadFile` so we can see what you're passing for callback?

Comment: @JarMan added details

Comment: "I want to access the object instance, so I can't copy it, right?" - Don't know what you're talking about but I said that the local variable `callback` goes out of scope because you only pass them by reference to the lambda and therefore the app will crash. Please read about lambda capturing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@chehrlic was right that you are creating a callback function that goes out of scope before it gets called. Your question does not need to be solved in a "Qt way". But signals and slots will work, so I will show you how.

First, connect your signal to your slot:

```
void MainWindow::DoNetworkRQ(QString url) {
    connect(&network_, &Network::someSignal, this, &MainWindow::onResult);
    network_.downloadFile(url, f);
}
```

Then, emit the signal when your network tasks are completed:

```
void  Network::downloadFile(QString& urlstr, const std::function<void (QString, QByteArray, QNetworkReply::NetworkError)>& callback) {
    auto processDownload = [&]() {
        QNetworkReply * reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply *>(sender());
        QByteArray result;
        QString filename = reply->url().fileName();
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) { // Success
            result = reply->readAll();
         }
        emit someSignal(filename, result, reply->error());
        reply->deleteLater();
    };

    QNetworkReply *reply = nam_->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(urlstr)));
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, this, &Network::downloadProgress);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, processDownload);
}
```

Comment: In this case the callback is not used at all, and the function `someSignal` from the network class will be connected to the main window's `MainWindow::onResult`  to do whatever I want with it?

Comment: Right, I'm not using the callback because you said you only did it that way when you couldn't get a slot to work. So I'm showing you how to get the slot to work. You would of course have to declare your signal within your `Network` class. Then `MainWindow::onResult` should get called whenever your `downloadFile` function completes its work.

Comment: Thank you, I finally understand the signals and slots mechanism!